# Called other Activity/CustomAdapter from an customadapter

Tags: android

In my code i just used two listview and two CustomAdapter for this two listView,in which first listview is implement through an CustomAdapter,from this CustomAdapter i just want to call another (Activity/Other custom Adapter for second listview).It gives Exception like

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   System services not available to
>   Activities before onCreate()

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ViewFlipper vfWall;
    ImageView ivComments;
    TextView tvComments;
    ListView lvComments;
    WallCustom2 adapterForComments;
    ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
    private static final String[] URLS = 
     {
      "http://lh5.ggpht.com/_mrb7w4gF8Ds/TCpetKSqM1I/AAAAAAAAD2c/Qef6Gsqf12Y/s144-c/_DSC4374%20copy.jpg",
    };
    String[] itms={"hey dude kya kar raha hai.........."};

    public WallCustom(Context context,ViewFlipper vfWall,ImageView ivComments,TextView tvComments,ListView lvComments)
    {
        this.ivComments=ivComments;
        this.tvComments=tvComments;
        this.lvComments=lvComments;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.vfWall=vfWall;
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return  URLS.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.wallcustom, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.Image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImageWallCustom);
            holder.Message= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessageWallCustom);
            holder.comments= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvExtraWallCustom);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

         if(imageDownloader.download(URLS[position],holder.Image)!=null)
         {
             holder.Image.setImageBitmap( imageDownloader.download(URLS[position],holder.Image));
         }
        holder.Message.setText("hey dude kya kar raha hai..........");
        holder.comments.setText("Comments ");

        holder.comments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 if(imageDownloader.download(URLS[position],ivComments)!=null)
                 {
                     ivComments.setImageBitmap( imageDownloader.download(URLS[position],ivComments));
                 }
                 tvComments.setText(itms[position]);
                 Wall wallobj=new Wall();
                adapterForComments=wallobj.ListViewForComments(); // gives object of second custom adapter
                lvComments.setAdapter(adapterForComments); // lvComments my second list view in which i want to set second custom adapter
                 vfWall.showNext();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder 
    {
        ImageView Image;
        TextView Message;
        TextView comments;
    }
```

Comment: Post the code for the Custom Adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

That error message is fairly straight-forward. You are attempting to use a system service, such as `LayoutInflater`, from the constructor or initializer of an activity. Do not attempt to use `LayoutInflater` until `onCreate()` at the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using systemServide(InflaterService) that cannot be use untill the oncreate() event is called. So the console error message is straight to understand.